# how to find that the array value not having more than three string?

Tags: php, laravel

How to check that `array[0]` not having more than three string("Idf").
For Example if user manually enter *Idfx.png*, I want to return error. In the same time numbers are also not allowed in `array[0]` value.

```
<?php 
    $initials = 'Idf.png'
    $initialsValue = (explode(".",$initials));
?>
```

Output:

```
Array ( [0] => Idf [1] => png )
```

Comment: `strlen($initialsValue[0])` [manual](http://php.net/manual/en/function.strlen.php)

Comment: strlen() solves the length. Seriously you could easily research that yourself in a couple of seconds... as for controlling the characters allowed in the filename, you could use a regular expression. Again, not hard to research. What have you tried for yourself so far?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do using below code

```
<?php
 $initials = 'Idf.png'
 $initialsValue = (explode(".",$initials));
 if(strlen($initialsValue[0]) > 3){
    echo "error";
 }
 ?>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
    if(strlen($initialsValue[0]) <= 3 && preg_match('~[0-9]~', $initialsValue[0]) == 0) { 
       //do something 
    }
```

this should work

Comment: Yeah great but this one allowing number

Answer (score 0):

Use [strlen()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.strlen.php) to get string length and [preg_match()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.preg-match.php) to check if string contains only letters

```
if (strlen(array[0]) > 3 || preg_match('/[0-9]/', array[0])) {
    throw new Exception('String too long or contains number.');
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This should work.

```
  <?php
   $initials = 'Idf.png'
   $initialsValue = (explode(".",$initials));
   if(strlen($initialsValue[0]) > 3 || (float)$initialsValue[0] > 0){
      echo "error";
   }
  ?>
```